# _splitpath in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, parsing

Is there a Linux equivalent of the Win32 API `_splitpath` function?
Details:

```
void _splitpath (
   const char *path,  // Path Input
   char *drive,       // Drive     : Output
   char *dir,         // Directory : Output
   char *fname,       // Filename  : Output
   char *ext          // Extension : Output
);
```

It takes full path as input and gives drive, directory, filename and extension as output.

Comment: It would help unix folks reading this if you said what (exactly) SplitPath does. Or link to some documentation...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`dirname()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/dirname/)  and [`basename()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/basename/)

Answer (score 4):

Not that I'm aware, no. What I'd do is:

- Run the path through `realpath()`, to make it canonical
- Just split it on the directory separator, i.e. the `/` character

Answer (score 0):

Use `dirname()` and `basename()`.