# Extract base path from a pathname in C

Tags: c, windows, file

### Question

**How do you extract the base path from pathname in C?**

**Are there any functions built into the C language or the C-Runtime Library to extract the base path from a pathname in C?**

I'm asking basically the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901624/extract-file-name-from-full-path-in-c-using-msvs2005) question.

NOTE: I prefer a cross-platform solution, but I'm working in Windows so if there is a Windows API call that does this, I'd still like to know.

### Examples

```
Input              | Output
---------------------------------
C:\path\to\file   -> C:\path\to\
C:\path\to\file.c -> C:\path\to\
C:\file           -> C:\
.\file            -> .\
.\                -> .\
\                 -> \
```

### References

- [Extract file name from full path in C using MSVS2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901624/extract-file-name-from-full-path-in-c-using-msvs2005)

Comment: @Rafe: but there is a runtime library!

Comment: @Rafe nits, but I edited the question with clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Windows there is [_splitpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

### Example

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Use your own error codes here
#define SUCCESS                     0L
#define FAILURE_NULL_ARGUMENT       1L
#define FAILURE_API_CALL            2L
#define FAILURE_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER 3L

DWORD GetBasePathFromPathName( LPCTSTR szPathName,
                               LPTSTR  szBasePath,
                               DWORD   dwBasePathSize )
{
  TCHAR   szDrive[_MAX_DRIVE] = { 0 };
  TCHAR   szDir[_MAX_DIR]     = { 0 };
  TCHAR   szFname[_MAX_FNAME] = { 0 };
  TCHAR   szExt[_MAX_EXT]     = { 0 };
  size_t  PathLength;
  DWORD   dwReturnCode;

  // Parameter validation
  if( szPathName == NULL || szBasePath == NULL )
  {
    return FAILURE_NULL_ARGUMENT;
  }

  // Split the path into it's components
  dwReturnCode = _tsplitpath_s( szPathName, szDrive, _MAX_DRIVE, szDir, _MAX_DIR, szFname, _MAX_FNAME, szExt, _MAX_EXT );
  if( dwReturnCode != 0 )
  {
    _ftprintf( stderr, TEXT("Error splitting path. _tsplitpath_s returned %d.\n"), dwReturnCode );
    return FAILURE_API_CALL;
  }

  // Check that the provided buffer is large enough to store the results and a terminal null character
  PathLength = _tcslen( szDrive ) + _tcslen( szDir );
  if( ( PathLength + sizeof( TCHAR ) ) > dwBasePathSize )
  {
    _ftprintf( stderr, TEXT("Insufficient buffer. Required %d. Provided: %d\n"), PathLength, dwBasePathSize );
    return FAILURE_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
  }

  // Copy the szDrive and szDir into the provide buffer to form the basepath
  if( ( dwReturnCode = _tcscpy_s( szBasePath, dwBasePathSize, szDrive ) ) != 0 )
  {
    _ftprintf( stderr, TEXT("Error copying string. _tcscpy_s returned %d\n"), dwReturnCode );
    return FAILURE_API_CALL;
  }
  if( ( dwReturnCode = _tcscat_s( szBasePath, dwBasePathSize, szDir ) ) != 0 )
  {
    _ftprintf( stderr, TEXT("Error copying string. _tcscat_s returned %d\n"), dwReturnCode );
    return FAILURE_API_CALL;
  }
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any functions built into the C language or C-Runtime to extract the base path from a pathname in C?

No there are not. Rules for path names are platform specific and so the standard does not cover them.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows you can use the API call "PathRemoveFileSpec" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748(v=vs.85).aspx

Cross platform solutions will not really be possible due to variations in file systems bewtween different OS's.

Comment: You can, except when you can't. Apparently the API is available for Windows 8+ only, thus not widely portable yet even when it comes to Windows.

Comment: @alecov `PathRemoveFileSpec` is available since Win2k. Only [`PathCchRemoveFileSpec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchremovefilespec) requires Win 8 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop from back to forward until you meet the first \

Comment: Not really going to satisfy the cross-platform requirement.

Comment: @David Heffernan why not? a for loop should be portable anywhere :P

Comment: @BlackBear I know, it's been some time, just in case someone comes across this: This is not an OS independent solution because `\\` is a path separator specific to Windows systems. [daalbert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6074847/2948765) noticed this as well.

Comment: @still_learning you are right, good point :) The question is tagged "windows" though

Answer (score 2):

WinAPI (shlwapi) [`PathRemoveFileSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do all of that with the exception of `.\file` which would come back as `.`

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard C99 function for doing this.  POSIX has `dirname()`, but that won't help you much on Windows.  It shouldn't be too hard for you to implement your own function, though; just search through the string, looking for the last occurrence of the directory separator, and discard anything after it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution on Windows is to use [_splitpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf(v=VS.100).aspx) as was suggested, to use something like [basename](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/basename/) on Linux (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613941/splitpath-in-linux)).

That said, since someone has already suggested implementing my own (and since I had already done it while I was waiting for an answer), here is what I came up with. It is not cross-platform and it does not check for /valid/ paths or expand short or relative path names.

```
// Retrieves the pathpath from a pathname.
//
// Returns: SUCCESS if the basepath is present and successfully copied to the p_base_path buffer
//          FAILURE_NULL_ARGUMENT if any arguments are NULL
//          FAILURE_INVALID_ARGUMENTS if either buffer size is less than 1
//          FAILURE_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL if the p_basepath buffer is too small
//          FAILURE_INVALID_PATH if the p_pathname doesn't have a path (e.g. C:, calc.exe, ?qwa)
//          FAILURE_API_CALL if there is an error from the underlying API calls
int get_base_path_from_pathname( const char*  const p_pathname,
                                 size_t             pathname_size,
                                 char* const        p_basepath,
                                 size_t             basepath_size );

int get_base_path_from_pathname( const char*  const p_pathname,
                                 size_t             pathname_size,
                                 char* const        p_basepath,
                                 size_t             basepath_size )
{
  char*  p_end_of_path;
  size_t path_length;
  int    return_code;

  // Parameter Validation
  if( p_pathname == NULL || p_basepath == NULL ) { return FAILURE_NULL_ARGUMENT; }
  if( pathname_size < 1 || basepath_size < 1 ) { return FAILURE_INVALID_ARGUMENTS; }

  // Returns a pointer to the last occurrence of \ in p_pathname or NULL if it is not found
  p_end_of_path = strrchr( p_pathname, '\\' );
  if( p_end_of_path == NULL )
  {
    // There is no path part
    return FAILURE_INVALID_PATH;
  } 
  else 
  {
    path_length = (size_t)( p_end_of_path - p_pathname + 1 );

    // Do some sanity checks on the length
    if( path_length < 1 ) { return FAILURE_INVALID_PATH; }
    if( ( path_length + 1 ) > basepath_size ) { return FAILURE_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL; }

    // Copy the base path into the out variable
    if( strncpy( p_basepath, p_pathname, path_length ) != 0 ) { return FAILURE_API_CALL; }
    p_basepath[path_length] = '\0';
  }

  return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before `str` is the full path and file name, after `str` is just the path:

```
char dir_ch = '\\'; // set dir_ch according to platform
char str[] = "C:\\path\\to\\file.c";
char *pch = &str[strlen(str)-1];

while(*pch != dir_ch) pch--;
pch++;
*pch = '\0';
```