# Splitting a C++ String with /

Tags: c++, string

I have a string in C++ like this: `"dirname/filename.ini"`. I need to get everything after the `/`.
How can I do this?

Comment: If this needs to be generalized, it tends to get very complicated. Use **[Boost::FileSystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-decomposition)** for this. Examples for [path decomposition](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Path-decomposition-table) here!

Answer (score 14):

Using `find` and `substr` methods from `std::string`.

```
std::string fullpath = "dirname/filename.ini";
int beginIdx = fullpath.rfind('/');
std::string filename = fullpath.substr(beginIdx + 1);
```

Comment: Assuming the OP wants the filename component, this won't work so well with `"dir/subdir/filename.ini"`.

Comment: i think it's better to use `rfind` in order to find the last `/` symbol

Comment: Is there something more dirname-filename aware? like dirname and os.path in python? Perhaps also dealing with windows \, dealing with ../// etc?

Comment: @Andrew right, I edited. I worked on his example, but `rfind` is much better.

Comment: @JohanLundberg probably boost.

Comment: only want to add: the same techinque you can use in **url**

Comment: For more file/path-aware functions, there's splitpath in the Microsoft world. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx, for linux see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613941/splitpath-in-linux

Comment: It will work fine with std::string::rfind(), or repeated applications of his method.

Comment: What about the standard Windows _splitpath() and Linux basename() ?

Comment: @acraig5075 it is not C++-cross-platform style

Comment: @loldop: filenames aren't C++ cross-platform either. *If* you want to split a string on the last `/` character, this is fine. *If* you want to manipulate filenames and paths, you should do something platform-specific, because splitting on the last `/` is not in general the correct way to get the last part of a file path (and neither is splitting on the last `/` or `\\`). Often the best way to do something platform-specific is to use Boost, since it presents the same interface on each system but does whatever it needs to behind the scenes.

Comment: @SteveJessop author said, that his task is to take from string substring, that was placed after last '/'. this task can be done by cross-platform style in C++ with `string` methods. i only said this.

Answer (score 11):

To extend on answer by Luchian, If the path can contain either forward or backslash characters use [`std::string::find_last_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of):

```
const int idx = fullpath.find_last_of("\\/");
if (std::string::npos != idx)
{
    std::string filename(fullpath.substr(idx + 1);
}
```

Comment: +1 Not everyone knows that Windows accepts either forward or back-slashes. Only the Command Prompt doesn't understand The/One/True/Slash/Style.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for splitting strings. It works with multiple occurrences of the delimiter too:

```
  char delimiter = '/';
  std::string tmp = "", originalString = "this/might/be/it";
  std::vector<std::string> parts;

  std::istringstream iss(originalString);
  while(std::getline(iss, tmp, delimiter)) {
    parts.push_back(tmp);
  }
```